# How to do multiple intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to do 3 intents to start a new activity,
however I find that I always get an error.
I'm putting my code onto main.java
code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
Button service;
Button gallery;
Button contact;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    service = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Services);
    service.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    });
    gallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    }); 
    contact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Contact);
    contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    });


        public void onClick (View v) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    Intent intent = new Intent (Main.this, servicesActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
        }
public void onClick1 (View v) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent (Main.this, galleryActivity.class);
startActivity(intent1);
}
public void onClick2 (View v) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent (Main.this, contactActivity.class);
startActivity(intent2);
        }

}
}
```

I have tried different ways and even putting brackets in different places. also I have been searching on the internet for weeks and found nothing that work with more than 1.
I'm getting errors on *OnClick and new View.OnClickListener()*.
I have got one working which is why I tried the same code with 3 buttons.
Basically I have 3 buttons on main activity.xml. All I want to do is:

```
>'button1 >goes> activity1'
>'button2 >goes> activity2'
>'button3 >goes> activity3'
```

Please give me any hints or tips as I'm new to Android dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main extends Activity {
Button service;
Button gallery;
Button contact;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    service = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Services);
    service.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent (Main.this, servicesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    gallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent (Main.this, galleryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);

        }

    }); 
    contact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Contact);
    contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent (Main.this, contactActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent2);

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: hi thanks very much for your reply but. i get an error which is Syntax error on token "intent1", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token .....whihch happen same for all the intents in brackets

Comment: Sorry.  what would i do if i want to add 1 more button. the button is R.id.home and would bring me back to the MainActivity.java. thanks so much in advance

Comment: Is your Main activity above MainActivity?

Comment: yes it is. the above code was in the Main.java. which is my homepage .thanks

Comment: In which activity  is R.id.home, because in Main you do not need this button.

Comment: in the activity contact, services and gallery wi ould this button "home" to bring me back to this home page we have here. thanks

Comment: You do not really need this button because if the user press the back button in the activity contact or services or gallery, Main activity will resume.

Comment: you're right i deleted the button. now im getting a force close when i click on the first button.thanks

Comment: Waitttttt i just realised all the buttons are opening the same main.java page. why is this

Comment: it works fine up until i change the coding for the service, contacts and gallery .java files

Comment: IM just think wether i even need any button on the other .xml ...i really only need the button on the homepage as navigation. what do you think? thanks

Comment: You do not need any button to go back to Main activity. If you have error when changing the code in another class, post as a separate question and post the logcat with it.

Comment: ok thank you for your help much appreciated.  im going sleep its past midnight here in uk....

Answer (score 3):

You can do all of them inside the same `listener`. Set all the `listeners` this way

```
service.setOnClickListener(this);
gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then use one function and check the `id` of the `View` that was clicked

```
public void onClick2 (View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
switch (v.getId())  // get the id of the Button clicked
{
   case (R.id.Services):
      intent = new Intent(Main.this, servicesActivity.class);
      break;
   case (R.id.Gallery):
       intent = new Intent(Main.this, galleryActivity.class);
       break;
...
}
startActivity(intent);
```

You can actually clean it up even more to not repeat variables with something like this

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();  // create an Intent
        String act = null;                     // name for Activity to start with Intent
        String shield = "com.your.package.";  // set package name
switch (v.getId())   // get the id of the Button clicked
{
   case (R.id.Services):
      act = package + "Services";  // if Services button clicked use Services as the activity
      break;
   case (R.id.Gallery):
       act = package + "GalleryActivity";
       break;
...
}
try 
{
intent = new Intent(Main.this, Class.forName(act));  // create your Intent by changing your String act to a class name
startActivity(intent);  // start the Intent as normal
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e){   // don't forget to catch invalid class names
e.printsStackTrace();
}
```

And as dymeh pointed out, make sure your `Activity` `implements OnClickListener`

This could probably be cleaned up a little more and may look more difficult but I use something like this in a custom menu and other places and it works nicely. It cuts down on separate functions and creating separate `Intents`. If you have to add something later or want to reuse the code it makes it a little easier, IMHO

Comment: Make sure your activity implements OnClickListener

Comment: @dymmeh yes, I hadn't gotten there yet. Thank you

Comment: hi thanks so much. but im a very beginner at this i dont understand where you want be to put where. so for  // name for Activity to start with Intent .... where about does it go. and after that as well. act = package + "Services"; <where does it go?

Comment: I am glad to explain. This is an `onClick` function so you just put it in your class, outside of any methods, like you would any other function. The "//" is for comments to explain what those lines do. You can basically use this function how it is, and use your package name for package of course

Comment: It may look a little scary but if you go through line by line it will make sense. I will be away for just about 30 minutes but if you have any questions feel free to ask and I will look shortly

Comment: thank you very much i made sense.the other guy above corrected his answer so i tried again and worked perfectly. i was slightly confused by yours. but thanks a lot for your kind advice