# OnClick listview inside dialog fix

Tags: android, listview

I cant seem to get this code to work at the moment.I would like to open a new activity with on click the list view I know this code is what am after but i have been playing about with this for days now and i just cant do it.

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {
    switch( position )
 {
 case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, superleague.class);     
        startActivity(newActivity);
        break;
 case 1:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, youtube.class);     
        startActivity(newActivity);
        break;
  case 2:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, olympiakos.class);     
        startActivity(newActivity);
        break;
  case 3:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, karaiskaki.class);     
        startActivity(newActivity);
        break;
  case 4:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, reservetickets.class);     
        startActivity(newActivity);
        break;
    }
  }
```

main.java

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

   public void popUp(View v){

    // Dummy list:
    ArrayList<String> dummies = new ArrayList<String>();

    dummies.add("BMW");
    dummies.add("FORD");
    dummies.add("ROVER");
    dummies.add("BMW");
    dummies.add("FORD");

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customalertdialogdctivity);
    dialog.setTitle("List Title");
    ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listrow ,     
    R.id.singleItem, dummies);
    listView.setAdapter(ad);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            //do something on click
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
   }   
  }
```

main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="popUp"
    android:text="pop dialog list" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Custom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

As i said if possible i would like to open a new activity when the list view is clicked.
I have looked and tried but no luck hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize your `Intents`, `this` refers to the `onItemClick`. You need to change it to the NameOfYourActivity.this

```
newActivity = new Intent(ActivityName.this, reservetickets.class);
```

Also, you should be using different variables for the `Intents` this way but you also can simplify the way you create the `Intents`. This will also take care of your other issue. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801306/how-to-do-multiple-intents/16801416#16801416). It may look difficult but I think it simplifies things and makes it more portable.

Comment: I cant place the code into my project as i dont know where to place it to see if it works

Comment: You would put it in your `onItemClick()`. Its in an `onClick()` now so it would be basically the same. You just replace `package` with your package name and `act` is just the name of the `Activity` that you want to start.

Comment: You would have to make some changes like `switch` on `position` instead of a `View`s `id` but its the same concept

Comment: http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/9252/18324662.jpg      this is the error when i put it in the onclick

Comment: You need to remove the second `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){`

Comment: And the second `public void onItemClick(...`

Comment: codeMagic thank you once again now i see it working and with what you said i know how it works in onclick and how the code should look

Comment: LOL this link you give me sounds just what i would like to do with this code next.I am going to try to code it myself before i post a question on it as i know il get it wrong.is there a way to contact you away from stack overflow.email.facebook.etc thank you

Comment: You can tag me on Twitter @codeInbody if there's something you want me to look at

Comment: Thank you am just working on this bit of code now...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801306/how-to-do-multiple-intents/16801416#16801416 getting error at break; ... the dots are where is at

Comment: The dots are an ellipses, they just mean that you may have more code after that which isn't relevant. Not meant to actually be in code

Comment: lol thanks iv found that in some case's its the little things that give lots of error so i didnt want to delete them.How new am i too this lol thanks again magic

Comment: can you help magic.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598355/open-multiple-listview-item-click-to-one-class

Answer (score 1):

Intent newActivity was declared many times in one block. Extract it out to declare only once.

**Edited**: Replace the `listView.setOnItemClickListener(...)` part in `popup()` method. As the second answer noted, you should use `MainActivity.this`, not `this` since `this` will refer to `OnItemClickListener.this`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
        Intent newActivity;
        switch( position )
        {
        case 0:  newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, superleague.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity);
            break;
        case 1:  newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, youtube.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity);
            break;
        case 2:  newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, olympiakos.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity);
            break;
        case 3:  newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, karaiskaki.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity);
            break;
        case 4:  newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, reservetickets.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity);
            break;
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: Not "insert", just "replace".