# Landscape mode error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an app in which I want the user to have other views in portrait mode than in landscape mode.
So I made 1 normal xml-fileen then made another one at which I signed at the making of the xml-file it is for landscape mode. So there automaticcaly was created an extra folder named layout-land in which the new xml-file (with the same name as the old one) is situated.

But whenever I start my app in landscape mode now it crashes (xml-file is for MainActivity.java)?

My xml-file for landscape mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/landscape1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Houd uw telefoon rechtop en herstart de app voor correcte weergave"
        android:textColor="#665252" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat output:**

```
06-03 19:22:14.664: D/AndroidRuntime(285): Shutting down VM

06-03 19:22:14.664: W/dalvikvm(285): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rome/com.example.rome.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at com.example.rome.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

06-03 19:22:14.684: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  ... 11 more
```

**Mainactivity.java:**

```
package com.example.rome;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton4).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton5).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton6).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton7).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton8).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton9).setOnClickListener(this);



}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageButton1:
          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Metros.class));
          break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Programma.class));
          break;
        case R.id.imageButton8:
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Italiaans.class));
              break;
        //-- more cases --
        case R.id.imageButton9:
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Telefoonnummers.class));
              break;
        case R.id.imageButton7:
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Kaart.class));
              break;
        case R.id.imageButton5:
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Restaurants.class));
              break;
        case R.id.imageButton3:
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bus.class));
              break;
        case R.id.imageButton4:
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Winkelen.class));
              break;
        case R.id.imageButton6:
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Syllabus.class));
              break;
      }
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Over:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Over.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.Hotels:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Hotels.class));
    return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


}
```

**activity_main.xml (Portrait mode version):**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0B0E15"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/metro2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/programma" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bus2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="175dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/supermarkt2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/restaurants2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/syllabus2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/kaartrome2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/italiaans2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/telefoon2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Streeptop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="______________________________________________"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Streep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Streeptop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:text="_______________________________"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Ide

Comment: Can you post the logcat when it crashes?

Comment: Can you post the Logcat output for the crash?  And to clarify, you have two XML files named "xml-file.xml", one in the layout folder and one in the layout-land folder?  Also, your RelativeLayout is missing the opening "<" tag, although I doubt that's your issue, probably a copy-paste miscue.

Comment: I got two files named activity_main.xml The opening tag is copy-paste miscue yes. I will give the logcat now:

Comment: Post your `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` and identify what is at line 21. Something there is `null`...probably a `View` you have in portrait `layout` but not landscape `layout`

Comment: I edited and include Mainactivity.java and activity_main.xml for portrait mode. There are a lot of views I have in the portrait mode version that I don't have in landscape mode version of the xml file, does that cause problems?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. When you try to call a method on a `View` that is `null` or set a `listener` on one then you will get `NPE`. I have posted an answer that should help

Comment: Yes, I did, just by auto-switching my activity to portrait-mode. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

The following video from the Android Developer Conference shows examples of micro and macro reflow (starts at about 11min).
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl3-lzlzOJI

For basic macro-reflow (aka land vs portrait) you want to have:

-the portrait view in the file:
res/layout/your_xml_file.xml

-the landscape view in the file:
res/layout-land/your_xml_file.xml

Thats 2 files with the same name in two separate folders. There appears to be nothing wring with your xml code.

Comment: I have just the thing you say and now I even moved my portrait file to res/layout/layout-port and in portrait mode everyting is fine but in landscape the app still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the `onClickListener` for all of these `Buttons` which apparently don't exist in landscape orienation. You need to put a check in there either if the `Buttons` are `null` don't set the listener or better yet check which `layout` is inflated or which orientation the device is in.

I could give examples of doing the above, however, since you are using the same listener for all of the `Buttons` it would probably be easier to set the `onClick` in the xml portrait file. For each `Button` do something like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:onClick="functionName"
```

then in your java code just name the `onClick` to whatever you used in the xml and you don't have to set those listeners in `onCreate()`. So you wouldn't need `implements View.OnClickListener` and could take out all of the

```
findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);
```

[This SO answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801306/how-to-do-multiple-intents/16801416#16801416) may help make creating the `Intents` more efficient. I like it but may or may not be for you.

Comment: But then it doesn't cause any trouble that in the @override section beneath it I have code with case r.id.......etc......?

Comment: Now the links (intents) crash?

Comment: The `switch` would still work. You have a separate issue if your `Intents` aren't working. Were they working before?